# Implement toggle in Backbone.js events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'd like to implement a reversible animation in Backbone, in the same way we do it in jquery :

```
$('a.contact').toggle(
function(){
    // odd clicks
},
function(){
    // even clicks
});
```

my question is how to do this in backbone's event syntax?
How to do I mimic the function, function setup?

```
events : {
  'click .toggleDiv' : this.doToggle
},

doToggle : function() { ??? }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Backbone's view events delegate directly to jQuery, and give you access to all of the standard DOM event arguments through the callback method. So, you can easily call jQuery's toggle method on the element:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "click a.contact": "linkClicked"
  },

  linkClicked: function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).toggle(
      function() {
        // odd clicks
      },
      function() {
        // even clicks
      }
    );
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Derick Bailey! I figured I could do something like this but it didn't occur to me to use the currentTarget

Comment: I don't believe that this is correct @Derick. jQuery's toggle with two parameters will add a click event handler to e.currentTarget that will call those functions on even/odd clicks. If you use this, every time a.contact is clicked, new handlers will be added again.

Comment: uhhhh yeah. not sure what i was thinking when i answered with that :P

Comment: Yep @DerickBailey, this doesnt work properly as expected. Multiple click handlers get activated.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a solution to this problem and I just went about it the old fashioned way. I also wanted to be able to locate my hideText() method from other views in my app.

So now I can check the status of the 'showmeState' from any other view and run either hideText() or showText() depending on what I want to do with it. I have tried to simplify the code below by removing things like render and initialize to make the example more clear.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click': 'toggleContent'
  },
  showmeState: true,
  toggleContent: function(){
    if (this.showmeState === false) {
      this.showText();
    } else {
      this.hideText();
    }
  },
  hideText: function() {
    this.$el.find('p').hide();
    this.showmeState = false;
  },
  showText: function() {
    this.$el.find('p').show();
    this.showmeState = true;
  }
});

var view = new View();
```

Comment: This works flawlessly. The accepted answer didnt work properly for me at least, where I had  multiple toggle events for same class running.

Answer (score 0):

Is the element you want to toggle within the view receiving the event? If so:

```
doToggle: function() {
  this.$("a.contact").toggle()
}
```

Comment: you could optimize this, because doToggle occurs during click. You got `event.target` as the target element of click so `toggle:function(ev){$(ev.target).toggle()}` should do ok

Answer (score 0):

I actually believe the only to do this using `events` is to add a `trigger` in order to keep the actual flow together. It seems a bit clumsy to be honest to have to use toggle in this way.

```
Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "click .button": "doToggle"
  },

  doToggle: function(e){
    var myEle = $(e.currentTarget);
    $(e.currentTarget).toggle(
      function() {
        // odd clicks
      },
      function() {
        // even clicks
      }
    );
    myEle.trigger('click');
  }

});
```

It's probably cleaner to just use

```
Backbone.View.extend({

  el: '#el',

  initalize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  doToggle: {
    var myEle = this.$el.find('.myEle');
    myEle.toggle(
      function() {
        // odd clicks
      },
      function() {
        // even clicks
      }
    );
  },

  render: function(e){


    //other stuff

    this.doToggle();

   return this;
  }

});
```